# Reference to a .ts file is not getting updated. How to update it when ts file gets converted to a js file?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have code like this:

```
child_process.fork("../someFile.ts")
```

this is not getting updated, its staying as .ts rather than .js . How to get it to be like:

```
child_process.fork("../someFile.js")
```

Comment: do you use "tsc" from cli to convert ts to js? or do you use it from any build/bundling tool?

Comment: yes i am using tsc. No I am not using any build tool apart from using tsc to form a dist foler with all the js files.

Comment: where is this code child_process.fork("../someFile.js")  written?

Comment: child_process.fork("../someFile.ts")  is the code. It's written in a ts file.

Answer (score 0):

Try instead:

```
child_process.fork("../someFile")
```

I don't know which build tool you are using, but might help you out!